# Passing a Variable in vue.js Component Modal Window

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

Initial question:
I am using a modal window in vue.js, which is launched from the parent module with the following code:

```
    <button v-on:click="openModal">Begin</button>
    <Account v-if="showModal" :showModal=showModal></Account>
```

The openModal function consists of the following:

```
openModal () {
  this.showModal = true
}
```

The modal window, which consists of a vue component (named Account), is opening properly. However, I would like to pass a variable to my component as a parameter, but I am not sure how to implement this.

Modified code which answers my initial question. I have added the :var="var" props parameter to the Account module.

```
    <button v-on:click="openModal()">Begin</button>
    <Account v-if="showModal" :var="var" :showModal=showModal></Account>
```

And needed to also add the "var: variable" to the data:

```
data () {
 return {
   var: variable,
   showModal: false
 }
}
```

And, finally the props in the component:

```
props: ['var']
```

Comment: Have you considered reading Vue's [Event Handling](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html) docs? Point being: `v-on:clicked` doesn't exist. You probably meant `v-on:click` ( shorthand: `@click`).

Comment: Actually, you have made me realized that the v-on:clicked is used to close my modal window (via a this.$emit('clicked') found in the child component) and not to launched my actual modal window. I have modified my question. Thank you.

Comment: Without more detail (a [mcve]) your question cannot be answered. It's unclear where `onChildClick` is defined, what is `clicked`, when is it emitted and where you expect the data (to/from).

Comment: It seems like you want to know how to pass a prop, but you've done so with `:showModal=showModal`

Comment: Actually, I would like to pass an additional parameter from the first line of code above, which opens the modal window.

Comment: Additional parameter where?  What you call passing a parameter to a component is the very purpose of props.

Comment: Thank you all whom have provided comments and answers. I wasn't properly understanding my own code, which originated from an example found online. I have provided a modification of my code which now works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that you are trying pass data into the component or get data from the component.

If you are passing value to the component:

```
Vue.component('account', {
  props: ['data'],
  template: '<h3>{{ data }}</h3>'
})
```

```
<account data="some-value"></account>
```

---

If you are trying emit value out from the component:

Inside your component

```
<button v-on:click="$emit('onChildClick', 'some-value')">
  Click me
</button>
```

When you call your component

```
<Account v-if="showModal" :showModal=showModal v-on:onChildClick="getChildValue"></Account>
```

```
methods: {
  getChildValue: function (payload) {
    console.log(payload)
  }
}
```

You can learn more about pass data between components in this article, please visit https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/01/data-components-vue-js/

Hope this help.